# error - a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, sails.js

I'm using Sails in a project with the module async series.

I got the warning below when executing the code:

> "Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it"

Here is my code:

```js
  addEntity: function (req, res){   **// LINE 11**
    async.series([
      function (callback) {
        Entities.create({
          name: req.body.entity.name,
          type: req.body.entity.type.name
        }).then(function (_entity) {
          this.entity = _entity;
          callback();
        }, function (err){
          res.send({message: "Issue ..."});
        });
      },
      function (callback) { **// LINE 24**
        var where = {
          caracteristique: { 'like': '%'+req.body.entity.caracteristique.name+'%'}
        };
        Products.find(where).then(function (_pr) {
          this.products = _pr;
          callback();
        }, function (err){
          res.send({message: "Issue ..."});
        });
      },
      function (callback) { **// LINE 35**
        this.products.forEach(function (el){ 
          delete el.id;
          el.et_id = this.entity.et_id;
          Products.create(el).then(function (_newPr) {
          }, function(err) {
            return res.send({message: "Issue ..."})
          });
          callback();
        });
      },
    ], function(err, results){ **// LINE 46**
      if(err) return res.send({message: 'An Error occured'});
      res.json({'entity': this.entity});
    });
  }
```

Details of the Error:

```html
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:417:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:320:18)
    at callback.success (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:31)
    at _switch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:58:28)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:248:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
From previous event:
    at Deferred.toPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:494:61)
    at Deferred.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:505:15)
    at async.series.callback.products.forEach.el.et_id (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:27:30)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at Entities.create.then.res.send.message (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:18:11)
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:417:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:320:18)
From previous event:
    at Deferred.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:505:27)
    at async.series.where.caracteristique.like (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:16:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at _parallel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:712:9)
    at Object.async.series (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:734:9)
    at Object.module.exports.addEntity (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:11:11)
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
    at module.exports (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/policies/sessionAuth.js:17:12)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
Unhandled rejection Error: Callback was already called.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:43:36
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:42:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at async.series.res.send.message (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:35:23)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at Products.find.then.res.send.message (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:29:11)
From previous event:
    at Deferred.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:505:27)
    at async.series.where.caracteristique.like (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:16:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at _parallel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:712:9)
    at Object.async.series (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:734:9)
    at Object.module.exports.addEntity (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/controllers/EntitiesController.js:11:11)
    at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
    at module.exports (/Users/musecz/Lab/HUB/api/policies/sessionAuth.js:17:12)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
```

Comment: plz update the complete error since that has more details

Comment: Sorry for this omissions.

Comment: Can you tell me at which line you get these error coz in error it says in EntityController 49,43,19, 13 ets....specify thes lines in the code

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. Does it work?

Comment: Yeah it works but I was wondering Why I had this warning and how i could remove it

Comment: You get the warning because you have a runaway promise that is not connected to a promise chain; you didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way and check if still you are getting the error...

```
addEntity: function (req, res){ // LINE 11**
  async.series([
    function (callback) {
      Entities.create({
        name: req.body.entity.name,
        type: req.body.entity.type.name
      }).then(function (_entity) {
        this.entity = _entity;
        callback();
      }, function (err){
        callback(err);
        //res.send({message: "Issue ..."});
      });
    },
    function (callback) { // LINE 24**
      var where = {
        caracteristique: { 'like': '%'+req.body.entity.caracteristique.name+'%'}
      };
      Products.find(where).then(function (_pr) {
        this.products = _pr;
        callback();
      }, function (err){
        callback(err);
        //res.send({message: "Issue ..."});
      });
    },
    function (callback) { // LINE 35**
      this.products.forEach(function (el){
        delete el.id;
        el.et_id = this.entity.et_id;
        Products.create(el).then(function (_newPr) {
          callback();
        }, function(err) {
          callback(err);
          //return res.send({message: "Issue ..."})
        });
        //callback();
      });
    }
  ], function(err, results){ // LINE 46**
    if(err) return res.send({message: 'An Error occured'});
    res.json({'entity': this.entity});
  });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still have my warnings. Thanks for your help